# Flutter How to recreate stateful widget in build()

Tags: flutter

I'm developing android/ios app using flutter with provider(state management)

in my app, i have a Main scaffold with bottom navigation menu. (so, one scaffold with many views and controll it using bottom navigation, NOT Navigator.push())

i want to know that is it possible recall initstate() from build().

for example

```
... Statefulwidget 

void initState() {
  super.initState();
  MYHttp.callAPI_only_once_for_some_reason();
}

Widget build(...) {
  var flag = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context).flagdata; // flag is true when push notification has been arrived
  if (flag) {
    initstate() // apparently it should not work, but i have to recreate whole stateful widget to call initState()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. The `initstate()` is only called each time a new widget is painted.
Instead of recalling the `initstate`. Create a method, add it to use init state and call wherever you want to call it.

Check the code below for an example. It works perfectly:

```
// create the method.
void makeRequest() {
    MYHttp.callAPI_only_once_for_some_reason();
}

void initState() {
  //call the created method here
  makeRequest();
  super.initState();
}

Widget build(...) {
  var flag = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context).flagdata; // flag is true when push notification has been arrived
  if (flag) {
  // call the method here again. if you need to use it.
  makeRequest(); // apparently it should not work, but i have to recreate whole stateful widget to call initState()
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: hmm.. method segregation is not fit for my circumstance. i've resolved it using Timer() in didChangeDependencies() that i really really don't want to do.. anyway thank you for your answer.